# How to route to a page with specific card details when clicking on a card?

Tags: reactjs

My cards have the info coming from a JSON file. Cards are all rendering properly, but I want to add an onClick function to each card rendered to reroute to another page I have called paintingInfo.js. In this paintingInfo file I want to display the image from the JSON file as well as the description. Can someone please help me out, relatively new to React.

```
class Paintings extends Component {
  state = {
    cardInfo: [...cardInfo]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar className="navCustom d-flex justify-space-between" bg="light" variant="light">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">SNR Arts</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="ml-auto navCust">
            <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/paintings">Paintings</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
            {/* print out cards here */}

            {this.state.cardInfo.map(card => {
              return (
                <div className="col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 my-3" key={card.id}>
                  <img
                    src={card.image}
                    alt={card.name}
                    className="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded indvCard bg-dark"
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought to do this in a simple way that doesn't require a major overhaul would be to define a method inside of the class called moreInfo(id).

Then in the .map inside the render, just like you are giving the image src, alt, and className attributes, you can give it onClick={this.moreInfo(card.id}}. I'm not 100% sure if this will work but I feel pretty confident that it would.

The way that I would tend to build this personally would be to make the stuff inside the return statement of the .map and make a component out of it. So it would be

```
{this.state.cardInfo.map(card => (
<CardComponent 
props
props
props
props />
))}
```

Edit: On my second read-through, I realized that I didn't give any actual render logic. My thought on that half of the question would be to render the moreInfo inside this same component. Keep a boolean in your state to track whether more info has been expanded or not. Put a ternary operator in the render() method that references that boolean. Put the current contents of your render method on one side of the ternary, and have the other side display additional info.

2nd edit: adding code block for proposed .map function, some of it didn't show up in display because of the markup.